# Can't start Mercure Hub on Debian 11 with supervisord, outh of Docker image

Tags: debian, supervisord, caddy

I'm trying to exec Mercure hub from supervisor, but is not possible for me. Mercure is in the same machine of webserver with the SSL virtualhost for `pami54.local` domain.

```
[program:mercure]
environment=JWT_KEY="m3rcu353cr37pa55pra53DEV"; CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS="https://pami54.local"; PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS="*"; ADDR="pami54.local:3000"
command=/home/frizquierdo/mercureLinux/mercure run -config /home/frizquierdo/mercureLinux/Caddyfile
process_name=%(program_name)s_$(process_num)s
numprocs=1
autostart=true
#directory=/tmp
autorestart=true
startsecs=5
startretries=10
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/mercureout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/mercureerror.log
```

**EDIT:**

I´ve founded a partial solution. In the Caddyfile I desactivated caddy server on port 80, setting auto_https directive to 'disable_redirects', staying Caddyfile on this way:

```
# Learn how to configure the Mercure.rocks Hub on https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config
{
   {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
   auto_https disable_redirects
}

pami54.local:3000

log

tls /etc/apache2/ssl-cert/pami54.local.crt /etc/apache2/ssl-cert/pami54.local.key

route {
    encode zstd gzip

    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Extra directives
        cors_origins https://pami54.local
        publish_origins *
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }

    respond /healthz 200

    respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

Its virtualhost config:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 #SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName pami54.local
   ServerAlias wwww.pami54.local

   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pami54.local/public"
   DirectoryIndex index.php

   <Directory "/var/www/html/pami54.local/public/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    #Require local
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
   </Directory>

   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2
   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
   SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl-cert/pami54.local.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl-cert/pami54.local.key"
   SSLUseStapling off

   <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|pl|asp|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
   </FilesMatch>

   BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

   SSLProxyEngine On
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   #ProxyPass '/.well-known/mercure' 'https://pami54.local:3000/.well-known/mercure' connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
   ProxyPass '/.well-known/mercure' 'https://pami54.local:3000/.well-known/mercure'
   ProxyPassReverse '/.well-known/mercure' 'https://pami54.local:3000/.well-known/mercure'
 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

On this way the clients can connect to Mercure on `https://pami54.local/.well-known/mercure`, even when a disconnection occurs the client successfully reconnects to the hub, but when server (webapp) try to publish a notification on the hub, symfony http client log error:

```
[2022-04-27T19:29:40.857698-04:00] http_client.INFO: Request: "POST https://pami54.local/.well-known/mercure" [] []
[2022-04-27T19:29:40.871491-04:00] messenger.WARNING: Error thrown while handling message App\Message\NotificacionMarcarComoLeidaMessage. Sending for retry #1 using 1000 ms delay. Error: "Handling "App\Message\NotificacionMarcarComoLeidaMessage" failed: Failed to send an update." {"message":{"App\\Message\\NotificacionMarcarComoLeidaMessage":[]},"class":"App\\Message\\NotificacionMarcarComoLeidaMessage","retryCount":1,"delay":1000,"error":"Handling \"App\\Message\\NotificacionMarcarComoLeidaMessage\" failed: Failed to send an update.","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Messenger\\Exception\\HandlerFailedException(code: 0): Handling \"App\\Message\\NotificacionMarcarComoLeidaMessage\" failed: Failed to send an update. at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/symfony/messenger/Middleware/HandleMessageMiddleware.php:129)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mercure\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Failed to send an update. at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/symfony/mercure/src/Hub.php:104)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpClient\\Exception\\TransportException(code: 0): The request was not processed and can be safely retried at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/symfony/http-client/Response/CommonResponseTrait.php:148)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpClient\\Exception\\TransportException(code: 0): The request was not processed and can be safely retried at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/symfony/http-client/Chunk/ErrorChunk.php:65)\n[previous exception] [object] (Amp\\Http\\Client\\Connection\\UnprocessedRequestException(code: 0): The request was not processed and can be safely retried at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/amphp/http-client/src/Connection/DefaultConnectionFactory.php:117)\n[previous exception] [object] (Amp\\Http\\Client\\SocketException(code: 0): Connection to 'pami54.local:443' failed at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/amphp/http-client/src/Connection/DefaultConnectionFactory.php:118)\n[previous exception] [object] (Amp\\Socket\\ConnectException(code: 111): Connection to tcp://pami54.local:443 refused at /var/www/html/pami54.local/vendor/amphp/socket/src/DnsConnector.php:108)"} []
```

What does this error mean that is throwing the symfony HTTP CLIENT component? I thought I had solved the problem. At least the clients connect an reconnect to the hub, now the problem is when the web application try to publish to the Mercure hub.

I must say that my local environmet have not an dns server, all is with local virtualhost and domains name declared in `/etc/hostname.conf` of Debian virtual machine:

```
#/etc/hostname.conf     
debiandev
pami54.local
```

Comment: and what is the business related question? If you're trying to access the service via a web server by the default port, then a reverse proxy would fit your needs

Comment: @djdomi I have actualized the post with a virtual host config. The issue is with the mercure server (caddy), if I set in the Caddyfile that it must run over port 3000, why from supervisord it try to run over port 80???

Comment: what happened while you stop apache and try to start the service first? second use grep -R 80 /path/to/configdir if you maybe set by mistake port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solution. In the Caddyfile I desactivated caddy server on port 80 assigning any other port, for example 8081, and  setting `auto_https` directive to 'disable_redirects', staying `Caddyfile` on this way:

```
# Learn how to configure the Mercure.rocks Hub on https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config
{
   {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
   http_port 8081
   auto_https disable_redirects
}

pami54.local:3000

log

tls /etc/apache2/ssl-cert/pami54.local.crt /etc/apache2/ssl-cert/pami54.local.key

route {
    encode zstd gzip

    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Extra directives
        cors_origins https://pami54.local
        publish_origins *
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }

    respond /healthz 200

    respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

Now, it´s possible for the clients to connect to the hub, but de web application can´t publish on it.

I have updated the post.